# Create new composition and apply a name Adobe cs5 script

Tags: javascript, adobe, after-effects

I need to extend the "smart import" script.
I want to create  a new composition.

then add each imported "element" to the composition as a track.
one track per image\sequence that's imported.

So what I need to know is how to create a composition through script,
and how to add a file sequence to it through scripting.

Answer (score 0):

```
myComp = app.project.item(1);
myComp.layers.add (app.project.item(2));
```

I resolved it by using the script above.
this assumes your composition is the only objects when starting.
then I import, and add the second item (this is my imported object) to
the composition.